# Eiffel: classical typecasting switch structure with attached and inspect

Tags: casting, switch-statement, eiffel

What is the best practice to do something such as

```
local
    l_pet: ANIMAL
do
    l_pet := catch_it_from_the_sky
    inspect l_pet
    when attached {DOG} l_pet as l_dog
        l_dog.eat (meat)
    when attached {FISH} l_pet as l_fish
        l_fish.eat (plants)
    else
        io.put_string ("Strange animal how do I feed him???")
    end
do
```

the compiler is complaining with the `attached` after when...

### Update: why such a need?

because it just happened me to mess up with repeated copy-paste which is what a language tries to help avoiding. In the above case, the `l_pet` is written one time, with a N times if/else I'd have to write it as much times as ifs...

Comment: There's a missing thumbsup button on stackexchange which says 'amuzing example' hope you enjoy reading me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `inspect` statement allows for checking if an expression has a specific value, and can be applied to expressions of integral types (such as `INTEGER_64`, `CHARACTER_32` or `NATURAL_8`):

```
inspect age
when 6 .. 16 then ...
when 18 then ...
when 80, 90 then ...
...
end
```

For discriminating over object types, conditional instructions are used:

```
if attached {DOG} pet as dog then
   dog.eat (meat)
elseif attached {FISH} pet as fish then
   fish.eat (plants)
else
   io.put_string ("Strange animal how do I feed him???")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-branch instruction

`inspect  exp  when ... then ...  else ...  end`

The `exp` expression needs to be a character or an integer expression.

In your given example I don't see the need to do that [Object-Test](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET-_Inheritance#Object_test),
but if you need to do something like that you need to use the conditional instruction.

`if ... then
       ... 
    elseif ... then 
       ... 
    else 
       ... 
    end`